# Akathist to St. Lawrence

Tags: eastern-orthodox, liturgy

Is anyone aware of an [Akathist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akathist) to St. Lawrence, Martyr and Archdeacon of Rome?  I have akathists to other saints, but not to Lawrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find an akathist to St. Lawrence [in russian](http://akafist.narod.ru/L/Lavrentij.htm), if that helps.

Comment: this is church-slavonic, not russian language

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ written in Russian typeset, yes, if you want to nitpick.